# Avoid splitting string columns when writing csv

Tags: r, csv

In a dataset, I have a few columns where the contents are names or addresses that may contain commas. For example, "Einstein, Albert" or "Devon St., 8". When trying to write a csv file using the write.csv command, R splits the strings and creates additional columns in some cases:

`write.csv(data, "output.csv", rownames=F, quote=F)`

```
Name          Address          NumberP           Phone
Einstein      Albert           Rue 8             8             00000000000
David Rosa    Ocho 9           11                0000000000000
```

How can I bypass this issue?

Comment: Alternatively, you could use write.table and change your separator to something else, e.g. "\t" for tab

Comment: I may try this approach to avoid writing the quotes, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `quote=F` parameter you passed in your call to `write.csv` might tip it off for you.  You told R to not quote the fields, which means that a column with literal commas will therefore appear in the output with literal commas.  Changing to `quote=TRUE` should get around this problem:

```
write.csv(data, "output.csv", rownames=FALSE, quote=TRUE)
```

Note that now your output will have each field escaped in double quotes, at least those which need it to be unambiguous.  But most place where you would import this CSV file know how to handle this (e.g. Excel).

Comment: Thanks, this useful. I hadn't realised the problem was coming from the Quote argument although it makes sense.  I was trying to get my output without quotes but I guess I can remove them later if needed.